# Writing an R code to create an adjacency matrix for a random graph and count the number of self-loops and parallel edges

Tags: r, matrix, graph

I am trying to write the code which creates a random graph by forming a random number of half-edges for each vertex, then randomly pairing the half-edges to create an adjacency matrix. The code I have written for this is as following.

```
# Set the number of vertices
n <- 100

# Generate the number of half-edges randomly
half_edges <- sample(0:n, n, replace = TRUE)

# Create an empty adjacency matrix
adj_matrix <- matrix(0, n, n)

# Loop through the vertices and pair their half-edges randomly
for (i in 1:n) {
  connections <- sample(1:n, half_edges[i], replace = TRUE)
  
  # Update the adjacency matrix by adding 1 to the corresponding entries
  for (j in connections) {
    adj_matrix[i, j] <- adj_matrix[i, j] + 1
    adj_matrix[j, i] <- adj_matrix[j, i] + 1
  }
}
```

I believe this code is correct, however I am having problems counting the number of parallel edges and self-loops. I understand the number of self-loops will be the number of entries in the diagonal, and the number of parallel edges will be the number of values greater than 1 in the adjacency matrix. I have attempted to write the code to compute this however the output does not seem to be correct. Please can anyone help me correct the following code to correctly calculate these values.

```
#Initiate values
self_loops <- 0
parallel_edges <- 0

# Loop through the rows and columns of the adjacency matrix
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {
    # Check for self-loops
    if (i == j && adj_matrix[i, j] == 1) {
      self_loops <- self_loops + 1
    }
    # Check for parallel edges
    if (i != j && adj_matrix[i, j] > 1 && adj_matrix[j, i] > 1) {
      parallel_edges <- parallel_edges + 1
    }
  }
}
# Print the number of self-loops and parallel edges
print(paste("Number of self-loops:", self_loops))
print(paste("Number of parallel edges:", parallel_edges))
```

The code keeps displaying self-loops as 0 and the number of parallel edges is far too high for what the true value must be. Observing the adjacency matrix I can see there are values for self-loops and parallel edges however these are not being counted correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with this half-edge definition of a graph so I may be a bit off, but the way you generate the graph 1) does not randomly pair the generated half-edges (it takes the half-edges and connects them to a random vertex of the graph) and 2) for each self-loop adds 2 on the diagonal of the adjacency matrix (`[i, j]` and `[j, i]`), not 1 as I would expect.

Comment: 2) is also (part of) the reason you always get 0 as the number of self-loops. As a consequence of 2), the diagonal elements will always be even and you specifically test for `adj_matrix[i, j] == 1` which can never happen. But even if it did, this condition is still not correct because in a multigraph that you create, higher values are possible as well. `sum(diag(adj_matrix))` would work for the self-loops.

Comment: Regarding the formulation of the graph, I believe its the configuration model which pairs half-edges. Do you know how I could adjust the code to pair the half-edges rather than connect to a vertex as I am unsure how the code would even begin to form this. Thank you for the help

Comment: I can try, however, I have a question: is the graph supposed to be directed or undirected (i.e. its adjacency matrix asymmetric or symmetric)?

Comment: It is meant to be undirected. Thank you so much

Comment: I have attempted to correct this problem however using the following code I get the error
Error in adj_matrix[i, j] : subscript out of bounds

for (i in 1:n) {
  # Find the indices of the half-edges that have not yet been paired
  indices <- which(paired)
  
  # Sample from the indices of the unpaired half-edges
  connections <- sample(indices, half_edges[i], replace = FALSE)
  
 
  paired[connections] <- FALSE
  
 
  for (j in connections) {
    adj_matrix[i, j] <- adj_matrix[i, j] + 1
    adj_matrix[j, i] <- adj_matrix[j, i] + 1
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier and more efficient to do using `igraph`:

```r
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_matrix)

sum(which_loop(g))
#> [1] 122

sum(which_multiple(g))
#> [1] 4352
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this definitely solves the problem for counting, however does the value for parallel edges seem reasonable to you as I thought this value would be much lower as I am trying to illustrate the number of parallel edges will follow a Poisson distribution and this value does not seem accurate, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: If you do `hist(count_multiple(g) - 1)`, this looks approximately Poisson distributed to me @scily09

Comment: It does appear to be Poisson so thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would modify the code to really pair the half-edges and also do it in a more efficient way.

```r
set.seed(1)
n <- 5

half_edges <- sample(0:n, n, replace=T)

# make sure the total number of half-edges is even
if (sum(half_edges) %% 2) {
  
  i <- sample(n, 1)
  half_edges[i] <- half_edges[i] + 1
}

# random pairs of half-edges (i.e. edges)
he_pairs <- matrix(sample(rep(seq_len(n), half_edges)), ncol=2)
# sort the pairs so that we will only fill the upper triangle of 
#   the adjacency matrix
he_pairs <- t(apply(he_pairs, 1, sort))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5    5
# [2,]    2    4
# [3,]    2    5
# [4,]    2    5
```

Filling the adjacency matrix edge by edge is rather slow so here I do it by more edges at once, specifically all *first* (i.e. all unique edges and first copies of duplicated edges), *second* (second copies of duplicated edges), ... copies of edges together. Since the graph should be undirected, we only work with the upper triangle of the matrix and copy it into the lower triangle afterwards.

```r
# Create an empty adjacency matrix
adj_matrix <- matrix(0, n, n)

# make a copy to work with
hep <- he_pairs
i <- 1
while (nrow(hep) > 0) {  # as long as there are unprocessed edges
  
  dup <- duplicated(hep)
  # process only first instances of each edge at this step
  pairs_now <- hep[!dup, , drop=F]
  adj_matrix[pairs_now] <- i
  # keep only duplicated edges for next loop (i.e. remove 
  #   those processed in this step)
  hep <- hep[dup, , drop=F]
  i <- i + 1
}

# copy the upper triangle of the adjacency matrix to its lower triangle
#   (make it symmetric)
adj_matrix[lower.tri(adj_matrix)] <- t(adj_matrix)[lower.tri(adj_matrix)]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    1    2
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    1    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    2    0    0    1
```

And this way you can compute the numbers of self-loops and parallel edges (although I am not completely sure how you define the latter):

```r
## From the adjacency matrix:
# number of self-loops
sum(diag(adj_matrix))
# [1] 1
# number of parallel edges
sum((adj_matrix - as.logical(adj_matrix))[upper.tri(adj_matrix, diag=T)])
# [1] 1

## OR using edges:
# number of self-loops
sum(he_pairs[, 1] == he_pairs[, 2])
# number of parallel edges
sum(duplicated(he_pairs))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful. Can you please explain the while loop as I'm unsure what each part does. Again, thank you very much

Comment: @scily09 I inserted a couple of comments there, does it help?

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much, I can follow it all now